# Найти первое вхождение символа и удалить все остальные вхождения этого символа

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пример: Есть строка 45.44.55.66, на выходе должно получиться 45.445566 Как это можно сделать, используя регулярные выражения?

Comment: `(?<!^\d\d)([^\d])` [демо](https://regex101.com/r/Bu0onl/1)

Comment: Думаю правильнее оставить верным ответ от ksa, мой ответ добавлен как вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть строка 45.44.55.66, на выходе должно получиться 45.445566 Как это можно сделать, используя регулярные выражения?

Такое можно сделать например таким образом...

```js
const str = '45.44.55.66'
const re = /\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d)$/
console.log(str.replace(re, '$1$2'))
```

Еще можно сделать вот так...

```js
    const str = '45.44.55.66'
    const re = /(?<!^\d+)\./g
    console.log(str.replace(re, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже вариант предложу с логическим или.

```js
const str = `45.44.55.66
123.4325.474.77`;
const reg = /(?:(^\d+\.)|\.)/gm;
console.log(str.replace(reg, '$1'));
```

Захватываем в первую группу цифры от начала строки и первою точку после них, остальные символы точки удаляются.